# map[int]interface{} не получается передать в функцию как map[constraints.Ordered]interface{}

Tags: golang, map, интерфейс

Есть код:

```go
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"
)

func Keys[keyType constraints.Ordered](mp map[keyType]interface{}) []keyType {
    s := make([]keyType, len(mp))
    i := 0
    for key, _ := range mp {
        s[i] = key
        i++
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := map[int]int{1: 1, 2: 2}
    Keys(s)
}
```

При запуске ошибка :

```
.\main.go:20:7: type map[int]int of s does not match inferred type map[int]interface{} for map[keyType]interface{}
```

Я не понимаю в чем.

Согласно [документации](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Ordered) `int` подходит под `constraints.Ordered`, так что и `map[int]int` должен подходить под `map[int]interface{}`

Comment: Да только `int` это не то же самое что `interface{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что тип `s`, который является `map[int]int` не соответствует типу `map[keyType]interface{}`, которая ждет функция `Keys`.
Чтобы исправить ошибку, вам нужно изменить `s` на `map[int]interface{}` или объявить функцию `Keys` с конкретным типом для `keyType`.

```
    s := map[int]interface{}{1: 2, 3: 4}
    Keys(s)
```

или так

```
func Keys(mp map[int]interface{}) []int {
    s := make([]int, len(mp))
    i := 0
    for key, _ := range mp {
        s[i] = key
        i++
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := map[int]interface{}{1: 1, 2: 2}
    Keys(s)
}
```